# How can I use function chaining with dates in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

consider the code

```
 const monthString = new Date().setMonth(2).toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'long' });
```

I would expect the value of `monthString` to be `'March'`.
however the output is actually

```
 '1,554,667,062,064'
```

On the other hand, if I break the actions into different steps

```
 const date = new Date();
 date.setMonth(2);
 const monthString = date.toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'long' })
```

the value of `monthString` is `'March'`

From what I can tell `setDate()` is returning a number, ie the date in ms.

Also the Number prototype has a toLocaleString function as well.

Is there a way with function chaining to override this behaviour?

Or is the only way to create a new variable and refer to it?

Comment: Javascript months start at 0, so March is month 2, not 3.

Comment: Fixed the error with the month index. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: What would you recommend as a title?

Comment: @ruakh updating thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Requiring this to be in a single line with chaining functions, you can wrap the resulting timestamp in another Date:

```js
const monthString = new Date(new Date().setMonth(2)).toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'long' });

console.log(monthString);
```

Alternatively, pass the month number into the `Date` constructor to get the month name.

```
new Date('2').toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'long' })))
```

Note: the number passed into the constructor must be a string.

```js
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12']
  .forEach(month => 
    console.log(new Date(month).toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'long' }))
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

`new Date().setMonth(3)` returns the unix timestamp, not the date object.
[Date.setMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth)

so

```
new Date()
    .setMonth(3) // => returns 1554667062064
    .toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'long' }); // => returns "1,554,667,062,064"
```

if you want to wrap it nicely, you can extend date

```
let DatePlus = class extends Date {
 setMonth(num){
    super.setMonth(num);
    return this;    
 }   
}

new DatePlus ()
    .setMonth(3) // => returns Sun Apr 07 2019 16:24:40 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
    .toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'long' }); // => returns "4/7/2019, 4:24:40 PM"
```

Comment: The OP clearly understands that: (s)he wrote, "From what I can tell `setDate()` is returning a number, ie the date in ms." (The link to MDN is useful, but doesn't answer the OP's question. It should be a comment instead.)

Comment: @ruakh thanks for pointing that out. updated to answer the question

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, but it's more verbose and less readable than just declaring a variable:

```
const d = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 2).toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'long' });
```